# How to optimize this references statements findViewById()

Tags: android, imageview

I have an activity with 80 ImageView, i have to add the references in my java file & I doing like this. Is there any way to simplyfy this code. please help me.

```
iv[0]=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv0);
iv[1]=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);
iv[2]=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv2);
iv[3]=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv3);
iv[4]=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv4);
iv[5]=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv5);
.......
iv[79]=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv79);
```

Comment: why does your activity have 80 imageviews?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `for` loop would be appropriate in this case:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < iv.length ; ++i) {
    int resourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("iv" + i, "id", this.getPackageName());
    iv[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(resourceId);
}
```

But optimise your code. Use a `RecyclerView` And show your images in adapter.
By your way you surely will get `OutOfMemoryError`'s.

Answer (score 1):

Dont do that! because of wasting time and performance problem. 
you can use listView or grid view to show 80 images.